# Function not reachable when called

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val res = Response.Listener<String> {
    fun onResponse(s: String) {
        doOnSuccess(s)
    }
}
```

The function `onResponse` is never used (not reachable from inspection scope) in the program while toast is properly executable.

Comment: Toast? What toast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [should be just](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

```
val res = Response.Listener<String> {
    doOnSuccess(it)
}
```

or alternatively

```
val res = object : Response.Listener<String> {
    override fun onResponse(s: String) {
        doOnSuccess(s)
    }
}
```

With your code, Kotlin sees it as the first form, except the body of the method just declares a function coincidentally called `onResponse` and does nothing else; it's the same as

```
Response.Listener<String> {}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @mTak stated, you missed the `override` modifier.

Here's the corrected code:

```
val res = Response.Listener<String> {
    override fun onResponse(s: String) {
      doOnSuccess(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: showing that modifier 'override' is not applicable to a 'local function'

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem is that you define an anonymous function `onResponse` in the lambda which is never invoked!

**A solution:**

```
val res = Response.Listener<String> {
    fun onResponse(s: String) {
        doOnSuccess(s)
    }
    onResponse(it) // invocation
}
```

**The better solution:**

Since your `doOnSuccess` seems to accept a `String` as single argument and it returns `Unit`, using a function reference is also possible.

```
val res = Response.Listener<String>(::doOnSuccess)
```

I did not test it, but in this case I think that you can even leave out the explicity type, because Kotlin can infer it from the function reference.

```
val res = Response.Listener(::doOnSuccess)
```